# Final Cut Pro 10 Change clip appearance of some clips in timeline

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

Is it possible to change the appearance of some clips in your timeline and not others?  Basically sometimes I only care about the main video and want to shrink any overlay pictures etc I may have to be as small as possible to save space, can I do this somehow?

Comment: This question is unclear to me. Do you mean if you can tread some clip different from others when you export a project?

Comment: No sorry, maybe if I give an example that will help.  I have my main video which generally I like to have larger, then lots of images overlayed which if possible I'd like to have at the smallest display setting/not show any audio track for etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you cannot change the clip hight for a certain timeline independent. What might help a bit is when you give your stacked clips different Roles and then click the 'show subroles'. What will move the audio to the bottom under the main timeline and will leave you with the clips only. Now click the 'Focus' button for your main timeline. Then all other audio tracks will get minimized to a narrow line. However, this does not help with the clip high.